# Postgres - how to find contents of one field within another field

Tags: postgresql, query, cast, pattern-matching

How do I find where the contents of one field are within another field?

I have a database table with a auto-generated sequence number in one field, and another character based field which should contain a string which describes a path to a file. The path should be based on the sequence in the other field, sometimes it isn't and I want to identify these rows.

This is query I've been trying (among others) but it doesn't work, *position()* is obviously designed to find a hard-coded string within a field, not another field

```
SELECT recordId, path
FROM TABLEA
WHERE position(recordID IN path) = 0;
```

`RecordId` is defined as:

```
recordId integer not nulll default nextval('tablea_recordid_seq'::regclass)
```

And `path` is:

```
character varying(80)
```

I can't help feeling that the correct solution is probably very simple, but damned if I can find it!

Ok, this works ...

```
SELECT recordId, path
FROM TABLEA
WHERE position(CAST(recordID AS CHAR) IN path) = 0;
```

Comment: Try casting `recordID` to `text`.

Comment: It sounds like you just want to check if recordid is not present within the contents of path, have you tried something simple like this, select recordId, path from tablea where path not like '%' || recordId || '%';

Comment: So is this question still open?

Answer (score 1):

> The path should be based on the sequence in the other field, sometimes it isn't and I want to identify these rows

So the *absence* of any actual position is what you are looking for, which is simpler:

```
SELECT recordId, path
FROM   table_a
WHERE  path !~ recordId::text;
```

Note the cast to `text` (or `varchar`, all the same).

Do **NOT** cast to `char` like you have it in your added (broken) solution. [`char` is a synonym of `character` (or `bpchar`) and defaults to `character(1)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html) (!), so effectively only takes the first digit of your number and produces many false positives. Related:

- [Best way to check for “empty or null value”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23767625/939860)

[`!~`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-TABLE) is the [operator for negated regular expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-TABLE)

[`NOT LIKE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) would do the job, too:

```
...
WHERE path NOT LIKE ('%' || recordId::text || '%');
```